# How to declare a variable accessible to whole function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ListSharedContentCtrl', ['$scope','$log','UserService', 'ContractService','ContentOwnerService','PlatformPartnerService',function ($scope, $log, userService, contractService,contentOwnerService,platformPartnerService) {
        $scope.init = function () {
            var contractIds =[];
           var contentOwnerId;
            var platformPartnerId;
            var user=userService.getCurrentUser('true');
            var contentOwner=userService.isCurrentUserIsContentOwner();
            var platformPartner=userService.isCurrentUserIsPlatformPartner();
            if(contentOwner == "true")
            {
                contentOwnerService.getContentOwnerId().then(function(savedContentOwnerId) {

                 contentOwnerId=savedContentOwnerId;
                 console.log(contentOwnerId);//here I can log the value

                },function(error) {
                    $log.error("Error fetching contract id:" + error.message);
                });
            }
        console.log(contentOwnerId); //but Here I cant log the value..Its showing undefined  
       } $scope.init();
    }]);
  })(angular);
```

Now my question is how to make the scope of the variable "contentOwnerId" available to whole function?Please anyone help me I cant figure it out..Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` right after your `console.log`

Comment: you mean `$scope.contentOwnerId` like this?

Comment: Yes how to make variable's scope available to whole init() method

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring contentOwnerId twice; once inside the if block, once outside it.  The one outside is declared, but never assigned a value.  It should be null where it is showing null.

Comment: if I doesnt decalre again will it retain the stored value

Comment: I have made the cahnges as you said but still its not working

Comment: I can see only one declaration of `contentOwnerId`, and then, inside the resolved promise, `savedContentOwnerId` is assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting the `contentOwnerId` undefined is that it is `undefined` until when the `getcontentOwnerId()` promise succeed!

if you do

```
var contentOwnerId = "before resolving the promise";
```

at the beginning of your `init()` you will probably have that string logged to console, instead of `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.contentOwnerId` instead of `var contentOwnerId`.

See `$scope.contentOwnerId` is available to whole controller i.e  `ListSharedContentCtrl`.

normal javascript variable are limited to functions where as `$scope` is available to entire CONTROLLER

Answer (score 0):

The .then() method belongs to a promise.
This means it won't be executed immediately, but later in the angular life cycle.

Your console.log() will always log 'undefined' because your variable won't be initialized there.
You can try this to log the value:

```
$scope.$watch( 
    function() { return contentOwnerId; }, 
    function(newContentOwnerId, oldContentOwnerId) {
        console.log(newContentOwnerId);
    }
);
```

Comment: Where to implement this code..I understood that the value  may not be initialized early because I m resolving it from a promise.Is there any method to bind the value to contentOwnerId as soon as the promise is resolved..?